# Subquery Excel VBA SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I need help with subquery in excel VBA. First: I need look for data by date -> for example from: 20.8.2018 to 21.8.2019 and Second: I need look for data by time from first result - > for example from 08:00:00 to 14:00:00

Now, I am looking data only by Date

```
strQueryQ7DrRightElox = "Select nio,checked FROM q7_dr_right_elox_incoming_inspection where date >= '" & sDateFrom & "' AND date <= '" & sDateTo & "' "
```

Comment: is `date` a field name? it's also a reserved word. use `[date]` instead or change the name of the field.

Comment: yeah , I have 4 columns nio,checked,date,time

Comment: What do you mean by " by time from first result " and what type is the time column?

Comment: I need get to data in certain date for example 20.8.2019 - 21.8.2019 and in certain time for example 08:00:00 - 16:00:00

Comment: Then add the same kind of condition you already have for your date

Comment: Do you think like that? : strQueryQ7DrRightElox = "Select nio,checked FROM q7_dr_right_elox_incoming_inspection where date >= '" & sDateFrom & "' AND date <= '" & sDateTo & "' AND time>= '" & timefrom & "' AND time<= '" & timeto & "'

Comment: I want to get data from 20.8.2019 to 21.8.2019 and from 09:00:00 to 22:00:00, and I don`t see data from 21.8.2019 at 08:00:00 because I set time from 09:00:00...I need to do formula so that data from 20.8.2019 at 09:00:00 to 21.8.2019 at 22:00:00 and I want to see data from 21.8.2019 at 08:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution . I have two columns Date and Time in SQL DB.Then I created another column datetime where is date and time together in one column and I can compare data correctly